# Authentication is not working in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am quite new in spring security. I want to use spring security features. I am using following code.

my security.xml look like this

```
<http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/sign/**" access="isAnonymous()"/>
<!--         <intercept-url pattern="/signin" access="ROLE_USER" /> -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/singout" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <form-login login-page="/signin" default-target-url="/home" authentication-failure-url="/signin" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </http>

     <authentication-manager>  
            <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userLoginService">  
                <password-encoder hash="plaintext"/>  
<!--            <user-service> -->
<!--                <user name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" /> -->
<!--            </user-service> -->
            </authentication-provider>  
        </authentication-manager>
```

User Login service code looks like this.....

```
public class UserLoginService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    IDaoSupport loginDao;

    public void setLoginDao(IDaoSupport loginDao) {
        this.loginDao = loginDao;
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer role) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles(role));
        return authList;
    }

    public List<String> getRoles(Integer role) {

        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (role.intValue() == 1) {
            roles.add("ROLE_MODERATOR");
            roles.add("ROLE_ADMIN");
            roles.add("ROLE_USER");
        } else if (role.intValue() == 2) {
            roles.add("ROLE_MODERATOR");
        }
        return roles;
    }

    public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        for (String role : roles) {


            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));

        }
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Person person = loginDao.findByProp(Person.class, "loginId", email);
        return new User(person.getLoginId(), person.getPassword(), getAuthorities(1));
    }
}
```

web.xml looks like this....

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

But when i using this code i am getting following code.

```
.service() for servlet [rrank] in context with path [/sample] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/List;)V
    at org.
```

can some body tell me whats wrong in this code.

Comment: It looks like you probably have miss-matched versions of some libraries somewhere. That's what `NoSuchMethodError` usually means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring framework lib version doesn't match with your spring security lib version.

you can choose the matching version from  [MAVEN REPOSITARY SPRING SECURITY](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/)

good luck